# Hacer una condición para que las fechas no pasen de un año

Tags: c#, asp.net, net, framework, telerik

como haría una condición en c# para que al momento de ingresar las fechas en el datepicker este me retorne un mensaje diciendo que las fechas deben ser igual o menor a un año independientemente de las fechas que le ponga, las fechas en si solo deben ser maximo de un año, como por ejemplo si pongo "desde" 1 de enero 2020 maximo debe ser "hasta" al 1 de enero del 2021 o "desde" 23 de enero 2020 "hasta" al 23 de enero del 2021, si la fecha de "hasta" es mayor que me retorne el mensaje diciendo que el rango de fechas solo puede ser igual o menor a un año.

```
int Year = 365;
if((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFechaIni.SelectedDate.ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFechaFin.SelectedDate.ToString())) <= Year)
  {
    NotifiMensaje.Text = "El rango de fechas debe ser igual o menor a un año.";
    NotifiMensaje.Show();
    return;
  }
```

psd: trabajo con c# net framework las vistas lo hago con las etiquetas de telerik osea el datepicker es un raddatepicker y bd sql server

```html
<td>
  <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="txtFechaIni" ClientIDMode="Static" 
  DateInput-Label="Desde:" runat="server" Enabled="true" 
  ShowPopupOnFocus="true" Width="180px" style="display:none;">
  </telerik:RadDatePicker>
</td>
<td>
  <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="txtFechaFin" ClientIDMode="Static" 
  DateInput-Label="Hasta:" runat="server" Enabled="true"
  ShowPopupOnFocus="true" Width="180px" style="display:none;">
  </telerik:RadDatePicker>
</td>
```

Comment: Eso es lo que eh intentado he visto una funcion en en c# getyear pero no se muy bien como usarlo

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que txtFechaIni.SelectedDate es del tipo Datetime

Puedes agregar un año así:

```
Datetime masunyear = txtFechaIni.SelectedDate.AddYears(1)
```

Entonces tu if sería

```
if((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFechaIni.SelectedDate.ToString()) && txtFechaFin.SelectedDate > txtFechaFin.SelectedDate.AddYears(1) )
  {
    NotifiMensaje.Text = "El rango de fechas debe ser igual o menor a un año.";
    NotifiMensaje.Show();
    return;
  }
```

Comment: El problema era que los datos me venían como Sting, y primero debía hacer la conversión

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien como estas convirtiendo los datos de DateTime a string, pero una opción es crear otra variable con la fecha inicial + 1 año (ó solo usar la misma fecha inicial + 1 año) y en la condición del if comparas si la fecha final es mayor a la fecha final + 1, entonces enviarías la alerta de error. Ejemplo:

```
DateTime fechaInicial = Convert.ToDateTime("05/01/2022");
DateTime fechaFinal = Convert.ToDateTime("05/02/2023");

var fechaInicialMasUnAño = fechaInicial.AddYears(1);

if( fechaFinal > fechaInicialMasUnAño){
    Console.Write("El rango de fechas no puede ser mayor a un año");
}else{
    Console.Write("Fecha aceptada");
}
```

Comment: Gracias Duver Gutiérrez el fragmento de código me sirvió a la perfección.